# how can i fetch the data from antd table expanded each time when i click on expandable button

Tags: reactjs

Till now, I have created a expandable table with antd and get fetched the data when I clicked the expandable button for the first time to show the data inner.
But when i clicked on the same expandable button next time, it is showing the data but API fetch is not rendering from the second time onward.
So, I need how can I fetch the data each time when I click on expandable button.

Comment: Kindly share some code example.

Answer (score 0):

Using useEffect hook and pagination on the api side, this could be done like this

```
const SomeElement: React.FC<Props> = (props) => {
  const [page, setpage] = useState(1)
  const [values, setValues] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    // api function
    getVal(page).then(res =>
      // expand the current array like this with new values
      setValues([...values, res.data])
      // pass these values to the table element and the table should expand by itself
    )
  }, [page])

  return <button onClick={() => setpage(page + 1)} >expand</button>
}
```